# Creating Future Call Rercords SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains Customers,Anchor Date(original sales date),Call Frequency(7,14 or 21 days). I need to use the customers specific Anchor date and Frequency to create and add future call records to a table until a defined end date. I am using SQL 2008

Comment: What kind of CTE have you already tried?  Do you have a numbers table handy?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a start:

```
declare @Customers as Table ( CustomerId Int Identity, AnchorDate Date, CallFrequency Int );
insert into @Customers ( AnchorDate, CallFrequency ) values
  ( '20130101', 7 ), ( '20130102', 14 ), ( '20130103', 21 ),
  ( '20130104', 7 ), ( '20130105', 14 ), ( '20130106', 21 ),
  ( '20130107', 7 ), ( '20130108', 14 ), ( '20130109', 21 );
select *
  from @Customers

declare @EndDate as Date = '20131231';
declare @Today as Date = SysDateTime();

with FutureCalls as (
  select CustomerId, DateAdd( day, ( DateDiff( day, AnchorDate, @Today ) / CallFrequency + 1 ) * CallFrequency, AnchorDate ) as CallDate, CallFrequency
    from @Customers
  union all
  select CustomerId, DateAdd( day, CallFrequency, CallDate ), CallFrequency
    from FutureCalls
    where DateAdd( day, CallFrequency, CallDate ) <= @EndDate
  )
  select *
    from FutureCalls
    order by CallDate, CustomerId
    option ( MaxRecursion 0 )
```

Comment: That was excaclty what i needed with just a few tweaks here and there.

Comment: Glad to help.  You can accept the answer, if it meets your needs, by clicking on the checkmark next to it.  See [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  There's plenty of other information available in the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).